# Finding the last element of a multidimensional array that meets a condition through recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, rendering

I know there are not so many real-life examples of recursion. I think I found one today and I want to share it Q&A style because I think it's fascinating.

I'm using the [Phaser](http://phaser.io/) engine for a game of mine. Upon a user click, I need to find the game element on which the user clicked. This becomes complicated once there are multiple elements one on top of another. Then, I would need to check their rendering order and pick the element with the highest one.

In Phaser, the root of all display objects is the "world". All existing elements are either direct children of the world or children of children. It's a branching structure with the game world on top. The children are ordered by their rendering order, meaning that the last one is on top.

Here's an example of this, having each display object represented by a number:

```
var world = [
    [
        18,
        3,
        [
            1,
            14,
            2
        ],
        5,
        9,
        [
            3,
            5
        ]
    ],
    [
        16,
        7
    ]
];
```

There are three levels in this array with two main "groups". In game terms, the second group is added after the first, therefore it's rendered on top. Inside the first group, the last element is rendered on top, which is a group. Inside that group, the last element is rendered on top again and so on. Out of all these elements, the one rendered on the very top is `7` since it's the last.

Let's say I click my mouse and it happens to be on top of all elements represented by a greater number than 10 (`18`, `14` and `16`). The one I need is `16` since it's the furthest down.

How do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with a recursive approach.

```js
function getValue(array, cb) {
    var last;
    array.forEach(function iter(a) {
        if (Array.isArray(a)) {
            a.forEach(iter);
            return;
        }
        if (cb(a)) {
            last = a;
        }
    });
    return last;
}

function check(v) {
    return v > 10;
}

var world = [[18, 3, [1, 14, 2], 5, 9, [3, 5]], [16, 7]];

console.log(getValue(world, check));
```

A version with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and a closure over the callback.

```js
function getLastValue(cb) {
    return function iter(r, a) {
        return Array.isArray(a) ? a.reduce(iter, r) : cb(a) ? a : r;
    };
}

function greaterThan10(v) {
    return v > 10;
}

var world = [[18, 3, [1, 14, 2], 5, 9, [3, 5]], [16, 7]];

console.log(world.reduce(getLastValue(greaterThan10), null));
```

Addendum inspired by 4castle's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41601330/1447675) with iteration from the back and return early with the first find.

```js
function getValue(array, cb) {
    var i = array.length, r;
    while (i--) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            r = getValue(array[i], cb);
            if (r !== undefined) {
                return r;
            }
        }
        if (cb(array[i])) {
            return array[i];
        }
    };
}

function check(v) {
    return v > 10 && v < 16;
}

var world = [[18, 3, [1, 14, 2], 5, 9, [3, 5]], [16, 7]];

console.log(getValue(world, check)); // 14
```

Comment: About the first snippet - what is the benefit of using `Array.forEach()`? If I use it, I also need to check if the current object is an Array to avoid calling it on a number. With a for loop if I try to loop over a number, its length would be undefined and no looping would be done. I suppose it can be problematic if `length` is present, but it isn't actually an array, though.
About the second snippet - can you explain a bit how it works? I've never seen `reduce()` before and I'm struggling to figure out what happens. I like the code, though.

Comment: you may add sanity checks before you call the function, or return if not supplied the right type. `reduce` iterates an array, takes a callback and as an option a start value. then it returns a new value base on the given or last value and the actual value. in this case the callback takes a comparison function `greaterThan10` and returns a function `iter` as a callback for return. inside of the function, it checks for array and returns either a reduce value or a checked value. another reason for reduce, you could write cool sentence like expressions.

Comment: to the question, why `forEach`, it is just atraditional approach with an outer variable for keeping the result.

Answer (score 1):

To get the last element of a multi-dimensional array that meets some criteria, you should use some kind of check to make sure that an element is an array or not, so that you know whether to make a recursive call or not. Finding out if something is an array could be done using [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), or you could use duck-typing and check for a `length` property.

Looping backwards over the array will help you find the top element quicker.

```js
function topElement(condition, array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var val = array[i];
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      var top = topElement(condition, val);
      if (top !== undefined) {
        return top;
      }
    } else if (condition(val)) {
      return val;
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

function check(num) {
  return num > 10;
}

var world = [[18, 3, [1, 14, 2], 5, 9, [3, 5]], [16, 7]];
console.log(topElement(check, world));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function topElement(fn, object, data) {
    if (fn(object) === true) {
        data = object;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        data = topElement(fn, object[i], data);
    }

    return data;
}

function check(num) {
    return (num > 10);
}

topElement(check, world); // 16
```

If I wanted a different condition, I would just change the `check()` method. In my game, the different condition is the place where the user clicked. `check()` compares the game element with the point, returns `true` if it's inside it and then `topElement()` returns the element furthest down the rendering order that met the condition.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjssmt1b/).